# Host Laravel website on Google Cloud using Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to host Laravel website on Google Cloud. But I am getting below error all time.

> This page isn’t working XX.XXX.XX.XX(My IP) is currently unable to
>   handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

So kindly let me know the app possible solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: We need more informatiion. A `500 http error` is a very general error. There are many things that could be causing this error. Such as file permission problems or incorrectly configured `.htaccess` and `index.php` files. Do you have any error messages within `storage/logs` that can help?

Comment: Have you set correct directory permissions? `sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache` & `sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`

Comment: Is this a standard deployment from Google Marketplace or a custom installation on the Compute Engine VM instance?